# PHP core code directory structure

Tags: php, directory, structure, subdomain, include-path

I'm looking to centralize a lot of my web applications code, so that multiple components have access to the same core functionality. This is how I have the website set up:

*/var/www/website - domain.com

/var/www/subdomain1 - subdomain1.domain.com

/var/www/subdomain2 - subdomain2.domain.com*

Naturally I've had a lot of trouble when it comes to the duplication of common functionality, as any changes made to one area would also need to be applied to other areas. My proposed solution is to create a new directory in */var/www* which will contain all of the core scripts:

*/var/www/code - core code*

I would then set the PHP include directory to */var/www/code*, so scripts can include these files without having to specify the absolute path.

Can you think of any more efficient ways of centralizing the code code?

Many thanks!

Comment: As long as your core code NEVER gets specifically changed for one of the sites, that works, I should say flawlessly.

Comment: Are they likely to be sharing client-side code as well? JS scripts and so on?

Comment: Khez - any code designed for one component will be stored in its own directory.

Cups - these components shouldn't be sharing client-side resources, apart from the likes of jQuery etc, but I don't mind duplicating small amount static code like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good enough for this purpose.

Little suggestion:
store your front-end scripts in directory like /var/www/website/www instead of /var/www/website. There will be index file and ajax processors and scripts like that. But your project-based inclusions (as well as other miscellaneous stuff) would be stored in directory like /var/www/website/includes. It is simple yet efficient defense from hacker attacks on your inclusion files

so, your document roots will be in /var/www/website/www (domain) and /var/www/website/subdomain/www/ (subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are thinking correctly :

[Share Code between multiple PHP sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748392/share-code-between-multiple-php-sites)

Answer (score 0):

It's only a suggestion, but you should put the public content in the `/var/www/*` which may end being publicly accessible—either because of your http server or because of some misconfiguration—and create some other directories for your shared code/libs like `/usr/local/lib/php/*`.

For more security you should frame it with `open_basedir` adding the private and public dirs—as well as upload and session dirs.

And don't forget to version your libs, e.g.:

`/usr/local/lib/php/myLib-1.0

/usr/local/lib/php/myLib-1.2`

etc.

Thus, you'll be able to make changes without breaking everything.